# How to insert new line after closed tags in Sublime or notepad++?

Tags: xml, sublimetext2, notepad++, xml-formatting

So I have this following XML file poorly line indented.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><H2HData date="19.08.2013 17:04:01"><Sport id="1" name="Futbol"><Country id="6" name="İsveç"><Tournament id="20" name="İsveç Allsvenskan Ligi"><Season id="9007" name="2013"><Stage id="19018" name="Lig"><Match id="11755684" name="Djurgarden - Hacken">
```

So what I want to do is for example, after a tag is closed insert a new line like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <H2HData date="19.08.2013 17:04:01">
        <Sport id="1" name="Futbol">
            <Country id="6" name="İsveç">
                <Tournament id="20" name="İsveç Allsvenskan Ligi">
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually want to *pretty print* your XML. In Notepad++ you can install the `XML Tools` plugin.

The problem is that in your example this won't work. The plugin will complain since the provided example is not valid XML (tags are not being closed).

Comment: Well it's only part of the xml file. Original is perfectly valid. I will check out the plugin you're talking about

Comment: OK that's good! Once installed, select from the menu `Plugins > XML Tools` the `Pretty print (XML only - with line breaks)` option.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Sublime Text, get the [`Indent XML`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Indent%20XML) plugin from Package Control. Once installed, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, or `Selection -> Format -> Auto Indent` after selecting the text you want to format. The plugin works in both ST2 and ST3, and can also be used to format JSON.